# A point on the Line of intersection of two planes

Tags: proof-verification, vectors

Let us consider two planes with equations:

$P_1 : x + 2y + 3z = 3$ and 
$P_2 : 2x-y = 5$

By substituting $x$ as $0$,
can I say that the point $(0,-5,13/3)$ lies on the line of intersection of two planes?

And if I find that the direction vector of the line of intersection is $(3,5,-5)$,
Can I say that the equation of the line of intersection of two planes is $(0,-5,13/3) + t(3,5,-5)$ ?

Comment: You can partially check your own work: The direction vector of the line must be perpendicular to the normals of both planes (why?). Is it?

Comment: Yes, the direction vector was calculated by the cross product of the normals. So it must be perpendicular to the line.

Comment: It _should_ be perpendicular, but it is really? One can see at a glance that $2\cdot3-5\ne 0$. Asserting that the vector must be perpendicular because it’s the result of a cross product isn’t at all the same as actually checking that it is: you must use a _different_ method than the one you used to generate the value in the first place, since otherwise you’re likely to make the same mistakes (if any).

Comment: "Can I say that the equation of the line of intersection of two planes is $(0,-5,13/3) + t(3,5,-5)$ ?" Even if you fixed the incorrect direction vector, the answer would still be no, because that's not an equation. What you *do* have is a *parametric form* of a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in the vector $(3,5,-5)$ there is a mistake.

I like the following way.

Let $x=t$.

Thus, $$y=-5+2t,$$
$$z=\frac{13}{3}-\frac{5}{3}t,$$ which gives the answer
$$\left(0,-5,\frac{13}{3}\right)+t(3,6,-5).$$

I got it by the following reasoning:
$$x=0+1\cdot t,$$
$$y=-5+2t$$ and
$$z=\frac{13}{3}-\frac{5}{3}t$$ or since $t$ is any real number,
$$x=0+3t,$$
$$y=-5+6t$$ and
$$z=\frac{13}{3}-5t$$

Comment: What did you do after representing x,y and z in terms of t? Yea I think the 5 should be replaced with 6, my mistake

Comment: And is the point on the line correct? Is it ok to take x as 0 like i did?

Comment: The point is correct.